# JQuery .post submitting twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to stop this JQuery POST call from submitting twice. Tried a few different variants of the unbind but don't understand it entirely.

I have seen similar questions, but they only state to use unbind, and not why or how for different scenarios.

```
$('.submit').click(function(){
    if (error != 1 && submitted != 1 && emailError != 1) {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'default');
        $(this).fadeTo(0, 0.50);
        submitted = 1;
        if($(this).parents('form').hasClass('ajaxSend')) {

            var url = $(this).parents('form').attr('action');

            var fields = {};
            $(this).parents('form').find(':input').each(function(){
                var name = $(this).attr('name');
                var value = $(this).val();
                fields[name] = value;
            });

            $.post(url, fields).done(function(data){
                $(".statusMessage").html(data);
                $('.modal, .modalClose').css('margin-top' , 120 + $(document).scrollTop() + 'px');
                $('.modal, .modalClose').hide();
                $('.statusMessage, .modalClose').fadeTo('fast', 1);
                $('.modalCover').fadeTo('fast', 0.80);
            });

            $('.submit').unbind('click').submit();
            return false;

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: and you're submitting `$('.submit').unbind('click').submit();` inside the click handler

Comment: are you sure it is the jquery triggering twice? It could be the default browser submit action. You _might_ need `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Even when I remove the unbind event or try preventDefault in the same place, it still fires the .post twice. There should be no default browser submit as it's not an actual form submit, i'm missing an actual .submit (when i didn't have it on the unbind).

Comment: shouldn't you be triggering submit on the form, not the submit button? Also, you probably should wait until the $.post is finished before triggering the submit event.

Comment: I think you should post some html to go with this

Answer (score 1):

what about disable submit button!

```
$('#form').submit(function(){

   var button = $('#submit');

   $.ajax({
     url: '',
     type: 'post',
     dataType: 'html',
     success: function(data){
       // if OK
       button.prop('disabled',false);
     },
     beforeSend: function(){
         button.prop('disabled',true);
     },
     error: function() {}

   });

   return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing this on the Form submit not the button click:

```
$("#my-form").on('submit', function(e){

  //do ajax stuff

  e.preventDefault(); //Stop form submitting via browser default functionality
});
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't help. I already know the button click rather than form submit isn't best practice. The button click gets rid of the chance that the form is being submitted normally via default browser behaviour.

Comment: Ok - but it's a common cause for thing happening twice - or never happening at all...

Comment: @Adam if you always return false or preventdefault that wouldn't be an issue. Also, you can bypass the jQuery bound submit event in that case by using the native submit method. `$("#theform")[0].submit()` so that after the $.post it will postback like it normally would have.